# Scala: comparing fresh objects

Tags: compiler-construction, scala, compiler-warnings

I was browsing scala tests and I don't understand why the compiler produces a warning when you compare "two fresh objects".

This is the test' outputs:
http://lampsvn.epfl.ch/trac/scala/browser/scala/trunk/test/files/neg/checksensible.check

Example:

```
checksensible.scala:12: warning: comparing a fresh object using `!=' will always yield true
println(new Exception() != new Exception())
                        ^
```

If I write a class implementing an `==` method it will also produces this warning:

```
class Foo(val bar: Int) {
    def ==(other: Foo) : Boolean = this.bar == other.bar
}

new Foo(1) == new Foo(1)

warning: comparing a fresh object using `==' will always yield false
```

**EDIT**: Thanks oxbow_lakes, I must override the equals method, not the ==

```
class Foo(val bar: Int) {
    override def equals(other: Any) : Boolean = other match { 
        case other: Foo => this.bar == other.bar
        case _ => false
    }
}
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Note that you should **never override the** `==` **method** (you should override the `equals` method instead). I assume that by a *fresh* object, Scala means a new object *without* a defined `equals` method.

If you do not override `equals`, the `==` comparison is a reference comparison (i.e. using `eq`) and hence:

```
new F() == new F()
```

will always be false.

Comment: This is apparently not true for case classes, where Scala performs extensional equality check by default. E.G. "case class F() ; println(new F() == new F())"

Comment: For case classes `equals` _is_ overridden.